# How is the height of a parent composable determined based on a specific child composable within it?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose

There is a column and an image composable inside a Row. I want the height of the Row to be determined solely by the variable height of the column. I want the height of the Image to be fixed and not affect the height of the Row. How can I achieve this?

```
@Composable
fun RowWithColumnAndImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    image: Painter,
    text1: String,
    text2: String
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text1,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Text(
                text = text2,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to give weight(1f) modifier to Image and Column composables. Kinda works but it affects width. I want a solution to affect only to height

[Visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZrjU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to match the height of the Row without defining its height, you probably need [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements#intrinsics-in-action). Try to adjust your code as follows:

```
Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),  // make Row height equal to smallest child
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text1,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = text2,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
    Image(
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()  // fill available Row height
    )
}
```

If you want your image to crop, you can play around with the [`contentScale`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/customize#content-scale) parameter of the Image Composable and see if you can get the desired result.

```
Image(
    painter = image,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, // This will crop the image
    modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
)
```

Comment: I prepared a [visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZrjU.png) . I want to differentiate design for old people that uses bigger text sizes. In SwiftUI I can give negative padding, it solves problem. But in Jetpack Compose I can not give negative paddings

Comment: Does the visual explanation show the problem or does it show the solution that you want? I am still not sure if I properly understood your question, but I edited my post. Is this what you are looking for?